# Jest - how to get useSelect data in tesing file

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, useselector

I have a component in the React project which uses 2 useSelectors to get data for rendering the page. While testing I am able to cover the UI part but the conditional UI part is not coming on, as useSelector data is not replicatable via mock. Can someone help me.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { id } = useSelector(selecetdId);
  const dataArray = useSelector(data);

  return (
    <div>
      {!id ? (
        <Fragment>
          <AnotherCustomComponent />
          {dataArray.length > 0 ? **<CustomTable dataArray={filteredSuppliers} />** : <NoData />}
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        **<div className="supplier-details">
          <CustomHeader />
        </div>**
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

As i dont have hold on the output from the useSelector id, dataArray, In testing i am not able to cover starred part of code

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are using ReactTestingLibrary and redux with dedux-toolkit ;)

You need to do two things:

1. Have a mocked state, with a values that can result in the condition you want to test
2. Render the component within redux provider

Quick sample

```js
const renderComponent(props, reduxState) {
  const reduxStore = configureStore({ reducer: {} /**/, preLoadedSate: reduxState });
  return render(<Provider store={reduxStore}><MyComponentToBeTested ...props /></Provider>))
}

it("Should show something if id in the state is undefined", () => {
  const stateSoThatUseSelectorWillReturnIdUndefined = {  john: true };
  const renderedResult = renderComponent({}, stateSoThatUseSelectorWillReturnIdUndefined);

/// expect something is rendered or not
});
```

More details here: [redux state unit testing](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function)